# Invalidate Firebase Token on Logout (React Native Firebase)

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

What is the correct way to invalidate a firebase token on react-native-firebase when user logs out?

Firebase's [deleteInstanceId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#deleteInstanceId()) isn't available in react-native-firebase.

In the Github issues, the following method was suggested: `firebase.iid().delete()`
However, after using this method once, I wasn't able to get the user to continue receiving notifications (using a newly generated firebase token) -- and the only way to start receiving firebase messages again, was to delete the app

This behavior happened on both iOS and Android.

The reason I want to invalidate the token upon logout -- is to make sure that this device will not receive notifications that are only intended for the user to see when logged-in

Comment: May this helps: https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging#deleteToken